# Keyword Search a single SQL Server table for multiple search terms and create a new table from results?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, full-text-search

I am not a database administrator. Most of my experience is with MySQL. However I think what I want to do is in the realm of possibility.

I want to text query a single large table in a SQL Server database for about 30 keyword terms. I then want the results to be dumped into a new table on the same database. I want the terms found to include entire field they were found in. (other items in row don't matter).

I am trying to produce data from the database to provide to a outside party. The table I want to search is to large to export to any format.

Is this possible?

Comment: What data type are the fields?

Comment: Character strings/varying. Its text.

Comment: What if the resulting table is too large to export to any format?

Comment: The search is very limited. Its extremely unlikely for the results to be to large.

Comment: I dont have the search already. I just saw your answer Will try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search:

```
SELECT col 
  FROM dbo.existing_table
  WHERE col LIKE '%keyword1%'
     OR col LIKE '%keyword2%'
     ...;
```

To put the results into a new table:

```
SELECT col
  INTO dbo.new_table_name
  FROM dbo.existing_table
  WHERE col LIKE '%keyword1%'
     OR col LIKE '%keyword2%'
     ...;
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked. In this case I only had to really search one column. However is it possible to search all columns in the same table without having to manually specify each? Right now I am having to replace the "col field". Also can this be applied database wide? (I will mark it as answer regardless shortly.)

Comment: @Sarge No, there is no concise way to tell SQL Server to just search all columns (or all tables). That seems to be a different question - it would require dynamic SQL and better requirements.

Comment: @Sarge You want something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Noob question. Do I continue the rest of the query with OR. Or is WHERE OR interchange.

Comment: @Sarge well, you're trying to match a bunch of keywords, right? You need an OR for each keyword. There are other ways to approach the problem (like a UNION ALL query for each keyword) but since I suspect this is a one-time operation this is probably sufficient.